# Problem retrieving information from the page and submitting it to the JavaScript object constructor

Tags: javascript, object

I wanted to create a simple form on the page with a few inputs and button and by receiving information from the inputs. I try to put the person's information on the screen, but the web page does not display the information well, but only shows `[object Object]`.

```js
function structur() {
  function person(name, family, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.family = family;
    this.age = age;
  }
  var name1 = document.getElementById('iname').value;
  var family1 = document.getElementById('ifamily').value;
  var age1 = document.getElementById('iage').value;
  var demo = new person(name1, family1, age1)
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = demo;
}
```

```html
<p id="result">show result here! </p>
<button id="show" onclick="structur()">click to show</button>
<input type="text" id="iname" placeholder="name:">
<input type="text" id="ifamily" placeholder="family:">
<input type="number" id="iage" placeholder="age:">
```

Comment: hello Tomalak ; Thank you very much for your accurate editing. Forgive me for the mistakes, I will be more careful in the next times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`demo` is basically a Object, which you are trying to insert in html, therefore you first have to convert it into String so that it can be parsed into HTML DOM.

```js
function structur (){
function person(name, family, age){
      this.name = name;
      this.family = family;
      this.age = age;
}
var name1 = document.getElementById('iname').value;
var family1 = document.getElementById('ifamily').value;
var age1 = document.getElementById('iage').value;
var demo = new person (name1,family1,age1)
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML= JSON.stringify(demo);
}
```

Few Tips:

- Use PascalCase naming convention for Object Constructor function, it totally depends on you to follow this or not, because it make more understandable code for other developers that this is a Object Constructor.
- Make as less side effects as you can, like in `structur`, your function is depending on value which is not in scope of person function.

Example:

```js
function Person(name, family, age){
      this.name = name;
      this.family = family;
      this.age = age;
}
function structur(){
    var name1 = document.getElementById('iname').value;
    var family1 = document.getElementById('ifamily').value;
    var age1 = document.getElementById('iage').value;
    var demo = new Person (name1,family1,age1)
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML= JSON.stringify(demo);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

the demo is an [object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp) and it's not possible to insert into HTML tag directly, if you want to convert this object to html you should add objects properties one by one to a string witch is contain HTML codes like this

```
function structur() {
  function person(name, family, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.family = family;
    this.age = age;
  }
  var name1 = document.getElementById('iname').value;
  var family1 = document.getElementById('ifamily').value;
  var age1 = document.getElementById('iage').value;
  var demo = new person(name1, family1, age1)
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "<p>Name: " + demo.name + "</p><p>Family: " + demo.family + "</p><p>Age: " + demo.age + "</p>";
}
```

the `JSON.stringify` method will convert object to [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp) string

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 function structur() {
 function person(name, family, age) {
 this.name = name;
 this.family = family;
 this.age = age;
}
var name1 = document.getElementById('iname').value;
var family1 = document.getElementById('ifamily').value;
var age1 = document.getElementById('iage').value;
var demo = new person(name1, family1, age1)
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Name: '+demo.name+',Family: '+demo.family+', Age: '+demo.age;
}
```

From object use **object.data**

> Like demo.name, demo.family, demo.age

```
<p id="result">show result here! </p>
<button id="show" onclick="structur()">click to show</button>
<input type="text" id="iname" placeholder="name:">
<input type="text" id="ifamily" placeholder="family:">
<input type="number" id="iage" placeholder="age:">
```